# what this type of series expansion is

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

I obtained a series expansions as this type

$$f(x)=g(x)^{\textstyle \sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_{i}x^{-i}+O\left(\tfrac{1}{x^{n+1}}\right)}$$

what is the exact name of this formula

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty ordinary asymptotic expansion for $$\frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}.$$

Comment: Except the expansion is in terms of 1/x.  Perhaps it has a special name still?  Gerhard "Maybe It's A Rolyat Series" Paseman, 2012.06.15

Comment: @Gerhard: An asymptotic expansion of $h(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ would normally involve negative powers of $x$, so I don't know why a special name should exist.